# Lorentz transformation problem

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, poincare-symmetry

[image]

**In the equation (1.18) they omitted the translation vector $a^\mu$, but why?**

Comment: Am I correct that you added the a here? Because the index is wrong, you shouldn't have three mus in one expression, it has to be a sigma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a constant vector (like the translation vector) is annihilated by the differential operator $\partial^\mu$.